# C# AvalonEdit Highlighting Regex till new line

Tags: c#, regex, syntax-highlighting, avalonedit

I am modifying the Code from the AvalonEdit in C# to create another syntax highlighting.
I want to create my own style for LOG-files the highlighted code looks like this:

[image]

Time in the front blue and the text behind green(information), orange(warning), red(error).
For single line Logs it was no problem but for multiline. So i changed my RuleSet to Spans:

```
<SyntaxDefinition name="LOG" extensions=".log" xmlns="http://icsharpcode.net/sharpdevelop/syntaxdefinition/2008">

<Color name="Time" foreground="#38a1d4" />
<Color name="Info" foreground="#69b26a" />
<Color name="Warning" foreground="#e1b561" />
<Color name="Error" foreground="#db5e5e" />

<RuleSet>

    <Rule color="Time">\d\d:\d\d:\d\d</Rule>
    <Rule color="Time">\d\d:\d\d:\d\d</Rule>

    <Span color="Info" multiline="true">
        <Begin>\[I\]:</Begin>
        <End>[\s\S](?=\n\d\d:\d\d:\d\d)</End>
    </Span>
    <Span color="Warning" multiline="true">
        <Begin>\[W\]:</Begin>
        <End>[\s\S](?=\n\d\d:\d\d:\d\d)</End>
    </Span>
    <Span color="Error" multiline="true">
        <Begin>\[E\]:</Begin>
        <End>[\s\S](?=\n\d\d:\d\d:\d\d)</End>
    </Span>
</RuleSet>    

</SyntaxDefinition>
```

But why does the End Span not work for my multiline??

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got it solved with the Help of dgrunwald on github.
The solution is nearly to easy. The AvalonEdit syntax highlighting machtes the code line by line. So the Regex is always compared to a single line. That's why it never can match a \n for a new line.

So here the solution:

```
<Span color="Error" multiline="true">
    <Begin>\[E\]:</Begin>
    <End>^(?=\d\d:\d\d:\d\d)</End>
</Span>
```

Now the result looks like this:

[image]

Thanks to dgrunwald!